# Doctrine cascade refresh not applied on relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have multiple entities that are linked together like this

```
Screening (1) --> (n) Customer (1) --> (n) Matches (1) --> (n) Risk
```

I have added `cascade={"refresh"}` on every `One-to-Many` annotations. e.g

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Risk", mappedBy="match", cascade={"persist", "remove", "detach", "refresh"})`
```

I need to modify the `Risk` entities in order to make some calculations and save the result in a `Score` entity, but I must reset the `Risk` because the changes must not be persisted in database (hence the `refresh`).
When I call `$entityManager->refresh($screening)`, the modifications in `Risk` are persisted in database. But when I manually iterate over each relations, everything goes fine. (here is what I do in the `ScreeningRepository`)

```php
foreach ($screening->getCustomers() as $customer) {
    foreach ($customer->getMatches() as $match) {
        foreach ($match->getRisks() as $risk) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->refresh($risk);
        }
        $this->getEntityManager()->refresh($match);
    }
    $this->getEntityManager()->refresh($customer);
}
$this->getEntityManager()->refresh($screening);
```

Why isn't the `cascade` annotation working with `refresh` ?

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong,. Take a look in source-code in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php. ->refresh() method.
`Refreshes the state of the given entity from the database, overwriting any local, unpersisted changes.`

I think you need to `->detach($risk)` (detaching from Unit-Of-Work) in order to skip changes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to detach cascade and I got the exact same problem, I need to apply it to every entity. There is no cascade. And `Refreshes the state of the given entity from the database, overwriting any local, unpersisted changes`, this is exactly what I want

Comment: `->refresh()` does not save data. So if you say data get persisted, then... something/somewhere else calls `->flush()` **before** you `->refresh()`.

Comment: .. And ...you do not need to iterate over all related entities. 
If you call `->refresh($match)` all `$risk` of this `$match`should be refreshed as well, since you have `cascade={"refresh"}` on your `$match` entity. The same applies for rest. Thees three loops, probably, produces many unnecessary SELECT queries. Do inspect your doctrine queries.

Comment: Yes I understand. But if I don't iterate, the `risks` are modified in database, which is weird. But no `flush` is called otherwise I couldn't refresh the entities to their previous state

Comment: Well something have to "change" risk entries in DB, otherwise they wouldn't be modified. Is there any other process that changes the date in DB ?
So if you just "refresh the page" what do you see in symfony profiler (doctrine panel)? Is there any INSERT/UPDATE statements?

Comment: They are not modified in DB. I change their state in the code to calculate something, and then I want to reset them to their previous state. This works if I loop through every entities and refresh them, and it doesn't work if I only rely on the cascade. So the code is basically the same, except in one case I loop, and I don't in the other case.